# CakePHP - Virtual field issue using Paginator?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, paginator

The following SQL query in phpMyAdmin returns exactly what I expect:

```
SELECT d.office_id, o.city, sum(d.`nb_followers`) as total_followers  FROM `data` as d
LEFT JOIN offices as o on d.office_id = o.id

WHERE d.`year` = 2014 AND d.`month` = 10 AND d.`day` = 01
Group by d.`office_id`
ORDER BY total_followers DESC limit 10
```

In my Controller :

```
 $this->Paginator->virtualFields = array(
            'followers' => 'SUM(Data.nb_followers)',
            'id' => 'Office.office_id'
        );


        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'Office.city', 'Data.followers'),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'data',
                    'alias' => 'Data',
                    'type' => 'inner',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Office.id = Data.office_id',
                        'year = ' . date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'))),
                        'month = ' . date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'))),
                        'day = 01'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'group' => array('Data.id'), //Mal positionné à la base mais vérifier si activé n'impacte pas les résultats
            'order' => array('Data.followers' => 'desc')
            //'limit' => 1
        );
        $dataTop = $this->paginate('Office');
```

But I get this Error :

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Data.followers' in 'field list'
```

SQL Query: SELECT `Office`.`id`, `Office`.`city`, `Data`.`followers` FROM `ebd`.`offices` AS `Office` inner JOIN `ebd`.`data` AS `Data` ON (`Office`.`id` = `Data`.`office_id` AND year = 2014 AND month = 10 AND day = 01) WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Data`.`id` LIMIT 20

Need Your Help  Thank you

Comment: Can you try to put this `'followers' => 'SUM(Data.nb_followers)'` inside the paginator settings in the fields

Comment: I already tried this but it's not doing the order by

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in my web app and putted a virtual field in one of my models. The virtual field was a field from a related table and it seems that it does not work. It outputs an sql error. So i remembered from the documentation the subquery command.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries

I dont know if this works but i will try to give you an example that might suite your needs

```
$db = $this->Office->getDataSource();

$subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields'     => array('followers' => 'SUM(Data.nb_followers)'),
        'table'      => 'datas',
        'alias'      => 'Data'
    ),
    $this->office);

$fields[] = $subQuery;
$fields[] = 'id';
$fields[] = 'Office.city';
```

I hope this guides you to the right direction.